# How to Order By with NULL in middle with MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef77a/6/0) for this question.

I have a students table similar to

```
student_id | first_name | doing_well
-----------+------------+-----------
1          | John       | NULL
2          | Jane       | NULL
3          | Steve      | 0
4          | Sue        | 1
5          | James      | 0
```

What I am trying to do is order the students according to the `doing_well` field. The students doing well `1` should be on top, the students not doing well `0` should be on bottom, and the students with unknown doing well status `NULL` should be in the middle.

I have tried using `ORDER BY FIELD()` with no success

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  students
ORDER BY
  FIELD(doing_well,'0',NULL,'1')
```

I would really like to accomplish this and keep the undefined as `NULL` and not have to change the undefined to a value.

The end result should be like

```
4  | Sue   | 1
1  | John  | NULL
2  | Jane  | NULL
3  | Steve | 0
5  | James | 0
```

***Alternatively***, Answers that can do the above using PHP to sort after the query are welcome but not preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also do this

```
    ORDER BY
    IFNULL(doing_well, 0.5) desc
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef77a/27)

Comment: any idea which way would be faster?

Comment: @amaster507 his answer takes 34ms  and mine 7ms . as his answer is checking 3 times with case statment .so this answer is faster.

Comment: I like this answer better as it is also easier to remember and shorter code.

Answer (score 7):

```
order by 
    case 
      when doing_well = 1 then 0
      when doing_well is null then 1
      else 2
    end;
```

Comment: could do `ORDER BY IFNULL(doing_well, 0.5)`

Comment: @TI it will work as `ORDER BY IFNULL(doing_well, 0.5) DESC` and which would be faster? This or this answer? They both work +1

Comment: @amaster507: I don't think there will be any performance difference.